# Makefile search rule

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile` that has a long list of targets stored in the `VOFILES` (I am building Coq code). In that `Makefile` I have added the following rule:

```
search: $(foreach ff,$(VOFILES),$(if $(findstring $(PTRN),$(ff)),$(ff),))
    @echo $^
```

and I invoke my `Makefile` with the following:

```sh
make search PTRN=lib
```

I am expecting this to build every target that contains the string `lib`, but it actually builds nothing. The `$^` is always empty (`echo` always produces a blank line). Is there a reason for this? Is there a way around it?

*EDIT*: The following rule prints a blank line, followed by a very large line. Is there something that would explain this behavior?

```
search: $(VOFILES)
    @echo $^
    @echo $(VOFILES)
```

Comment: It works for me (GNUMake 3.81). What happens when you put that `foreach` statement in an `info` statement? (That is, out side any rule, put `$(info $(foreach ff, ...`)

Comment: Is last comma necessary ?

Comment: I suppose it is the `VOFILES` variable which is empty in the first place. Your use of `foreach` is correct.

Comment: I'm on make 4.3 in Manjaro: `GNU Make 4.3`

Comment: I do not reproduce the behavior described with GNU make 4.2.1.  How about presenting a [mre]?  I would be inclined to guess that the issue is related to how (and when) `VOFILES` gets its value, but there's not enough information available to evaluate that.

Comment: What contributes to when a variable gets its value?

Comment: Factors in when a variable gets its value: where the variable appears lexically in the makefile.  Whether it is or the recursively expanded flavor or the immediately expanded flavor.  Whether there is an environment variable with the same name.  Whether a definition is given on the command line.  Whether additional text is appended to it (via `+=`), and if so, where in the makefile that happens.  And more.  The GNU make manual has [a whole chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables) on this.